# In Google Chrome extension, first call to chrome.identity.getAuthToken() gets valid token, but second call returns error “The user is not signed in”?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, token, access-token, identity

Within a Google Chrome extension, I am calling
`chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: false })`
to check if there is a valid token or not.

If the token is valid, I then can use existing token and make API calls, in my case Google Drive and Sheets APIs.

If there is no token, then I call getAuthToken() again, but set “interactive” to true, which brings up the Google login workflow (login, allow access)
`chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true })`

What happens is I can call chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }) and I do get a valid new token, but any call to `chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: false })`
after my successful call returns an error: “The user is not signed in”

Checking 
chrome://identity-internals/
shows I have a valid token, along with expiration date, etc.  So, why can’t I access this through Google preferred way to get, keep, and retrieve the token? ...which should be this:
`chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: false })`

Note, I also have a callback function in the second parameter of each getAuthToken call.  I left that out for simplicity.

Followed Google's guidelines and how to set this up using these resources:
https://developers.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_oauth

I implemented this with a personal/test app.  I also downloaded and implemented this example:
https://developer.chrome.com/apps/examples/tutorials/oauth_tutorial_complete.zip

```
chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: false}, function(existingToken) {
  if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        //No token, so try again with interactive: true
        chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(newToken) {
          if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                return;
          }
          //Do something with newToken
        });
        return;
  }
  //We never make it this far (should have existing token)
});
```

Basically, I expect to be able to login to Google, get my token (which I can do successfully), then be able to get this valid token for future use in my Google Chrome extension.

...but any call to `chrome.identity.getAuthToken({ interactive: false })`
after my successful call returns an error: “The user is not signed in”

Comment: I would use only `{interactive:true}`: if the user has granted permission, it will provide the token in the callback function; if they haven't, the authorization screen will appear. In my experience, there is no advantage in using `{interactive:false}`.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko that worked.  I just used `{interactive:true}` and let the Chrome Identity API handle if they are not authenticated or not.  I'm not sure why they even have the `{interactive:false}` in their documentation...seems to not work as they describe.

Comment: Happy to help :)